# how to receive a string via bluetooth in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to create a function that through a loop reads from the buffer a string received via bluetooth, this is what i did so far but it doesn't work, and if I use a while loop it just gets stuck in the loop, maybe I'm missing the right condition.

```
private suspend fun getmeData(){
        var bytes :Int
        val buffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
        var readMessage : String = ""
        if (m_isConnected ) {
            try {   

               while(){         
                   //read bytes received and ins to buffer
                   bytes =_bluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(buffer)
                   //convert to string
                   readMessage = readMessage + String(buffer, 0,bytes)
              }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                
            }
        } else {            
            val toast = Toast.makeText(
                contesto, "Non connesso",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            )
            toast.show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? Is there an error? Is the output wrong, if so, what is the received output vs expected output?

Comment: the problem is that i can't find some helpfull guide that explains how reading from a buffer works in android, beside i need a while loop that works with some sort of condition related to the buffer i read from. so where in the ''try'' on the code, inside that I  need a while loop to cycle and read from the buffer till it's empty

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys after an interesting conversation with a colluege i found the solution, the while's condition inside the "try" code must be like this,  since the string i m receving contains an end string symbol

```
 while (!(readMessage.contains(';'))){
        /*my code*/
 }
```

Thanks to everyone for the effort! <3